# Python: Passing variable from 1st script to 2nd script and passing different variable from 2nd script to 1st script

Tags: python, parameter-passing, try-except

These are simplified version of the scripts. I'm still working my way through learning, so they are
very rough.

```
** movieInfo.py **

def castInfo():
    castMbrName = inputbox("Provide name")
    castPageURL = "https://www.cast_site.com/" + castMbrName
    # Most pages match this format. Some don't. For example: 
    #   "http://www.cast_site.com/" + castMbrFirstName + "-" + castMbrSecondName
    # or
    #   "http://www.cast_site.com/" + castMbrAliasName

    # To make sure I have the right page, I search for the cast member's name on it.
    sourceCastPage = requests.get(castPageURL, headers=hdr).text
    soupCastPage = BeautifulSoup(sourceCastPage, "lxml")
    try:
        castMbrNameOnPage = soupCastPage.find("div", attrs={"class":"xyz"}).text

        # If this succeeds, I use castPageURL in the rest of the script.
        cast_mbr_url = castPageURL
    except (AttributeError,TypeError):

        # If not, I want send castMbrName to castPageURL.py
        return castMbrName #<<see note below<<

        # Getting the value from castURL in castPageURL.url into movieInfo.py
        cast_mbr_url = checkCastNameURL()

castInfo()

# Do other things with cast_mbr_url
.
.
.

** castPageURL.py **

# This script will take the cast member's name, search the db and either add the name and url if not 
# found or return the url if found.

def checkCastNameURL():
    # This is a TinyDB setup containing the names and urls that don't match.
    db = TinyDB(castMbr_db.json)

    # I want to import the castMbrName variable from movieInfo.py into here.
    cast_name_req = castInfo()

    # When I manually provided the cast name, it worked. Now, I want to use castMbrName from movieInfo.py

    # Search the db for the cast member's name. If not found, get copy of correct url from site and add to db.
    if db.search(where("cast_name") == cast_name_req) == []:
    cast_name_url = simpledialog.askstring(
        title="",
        prompt="Paste cast member's url from site:",
        initialvalue="",
    ).strip()

    # Add name and url to db
    db.insert(
        {
            "cast_name": cast_name_req,
            "cast_url": cast_name_url,
        }
    )

    result = db.get(Query()["cast_name"] == castNameReq)
    castURL = result.get("cast_url")
    return castURL
```

I want to send variable castMbrName from movieInfo.py to castPageURL.py and send castURL from castPageURL.py to movieInfo.py. The scripts work individually but I want to incorporate castPageURL into movieInfo.

My problem is I don't know what to import where. Any insight would be appreciated.

I tried:

```
** movieInfo.py **

import castPageURL
From castPageURL import checkCastNameURL # with and without this

** castPageURL **

import movieInfo
from movieInfo import castInfo # with and without this as well
```

I also tried this:

```
** movieInfo.py **

import castPageURL
From castPageURL import checkCastNameURL # with and without this

** castPageURL **

from __main__ import *
```

I even tried importing inside the function instead of the top of the script.

```
** movieInfo.py **

import castPageURL
From castPageURL import checkCastNameURL # with and without this

** castPageURL.py **

def checkCastNameURL():
    import movieInfo
    from movieInfo import castInfo # with and without this
```

I have not been able to get both scripts to recognize the functions from the other.

Also, in the "except" portion of the "try/except" block, once this is done,

```
return castMbrName
```

how do I get this to run?

```
cast_mbr_url = checkCastNameURL()
```

Please let me know if further clarification is needed.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't really comprehensible. Why do your functions call each other? They don't pass any information between them, so why do this? And exactly what is the question; what happens when you try these imports?

Comment: It sounds like you want to pass parameters from one function to another. The long established custom for this is to 'pass parameters' which in your case might look like: `cast_mbr_url = checkCastNameURL(castMbrName)`

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I want to send cast_mbr from 1st py script to 2nd py script to see if it is in the db. If it is not in the db, I want to add cast_mbr and the correct url to the db and return the correct url to the 1st py script. If cast_mbr is in the db, I want to return the matching url inthe db from the 2nd py script and send it to the 1st py script to be handled later. I hope that clarifies things.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to import a module, try to remove the `castInfo()` from the end of the file and replace it with

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   castInfo()
```

This is better because it will allow you to run the method manulaly, rather than it being run on import.

Also when importing from, the syntax is `from castPageURL import checkCastNameURL`, not `From castPageURL import checkCastNameURL`, It's an easy mistake to make, but try to remember that python is case sensitive.

In terms of where you should import the method, you should do it at the very beginning of your program.

If you want to import from you don't need the `import castPageURL` before the `from castPageURL import checkCastNameURL`, but you need to make it so that the `import castPageURL` is actually `import path\to\castPageURL.py`

Comment: I missed the full path for the script in the import. Thanks for that.
  
Just so I understand, I do this 
`if __name__ == "__main__":`
even though castInfo() is not the function being imported, correct?

**From s/b from**: sorry about that, too little sleep.

Comment: It's good practice to do it that way, however both should work. It shouldn't change the functionality of your program at all however.